# Vibration when at idle and in gear

Tags: toyota

I have a 2007 Toyota Corolla that recently had its front and rear engine mount replaced. After they were replaced, the car has been vibrating in idle as well as in gear while stopped. What may be the cause of this?

Comment: How many RPM's is your engine idling at?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Strong vibrations when idling even after replacing engine mounts (automatic transmission)](http://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/4430/strong-vibrations-when-idling-even-after-replacing-engine-mounts-automatic-tran)

Answer (score 1):

Given the sudden onset I would not be surprised if the mechanics forgot to reconnect something like an EGR hose or sensor connector that may have been removed in order to replace the engine mounts. A vacuum leak would explain this but it is just one of several possibilities.