# Vibration felt, heard and seen when in Drive at stop but disappears when shifted to Neutral

Tags: idle, vibration, drive-cycle

2010 Jeep Patriot FD2 4x4 38,000 miles 
Well maintained vehicle with low mileage. Excessive vibration noticed beginning 6 months ago. Have changed spark plugs, air filter, Premium gas used with double cans of fuel injector over three tank fill ups, throttle valve inspected and cleaned with Seafoam, motor mounts and transmission mounts inspected: all without improvement. Two separate repair shops have given up on finding the cause. Car runs great on the road but has vibration in idle while at stop in Drive. Vibration worse when sitting on an incline regardless of whether in Drive or Neutral. Great car except for this issue.  Have spent a lot of money chasing this with no results. What next? Compression Test, Coils replaced, ???

Comment: I doubt it's a coil issue as if a coil was failing, you'd get a misfire code (most likely). You can try a compression test, it may show you something. Did they check for vacuum leaks? If so, what did they do to check for them?

Comment: How many RPMs is it idling at?

Comment: What does it idle at ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Strong vibrations when idling even after replacing engine mounts (automatic transmission)](http://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/4430/strong-vibrations-when-idling-even-after-replacing-engine-mounts-automatic-tran)